# Can someone advise me on Rails memory consumption?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memory, memory-leaks

I'm working on a Rails application at the moment which seems to kill 
the memory on my iMac until I eventually have to restart. 
I have a 2.66 GHZ processor with 4GB Ram on OSX 10.6.

When I boot the rails app, the memory consumption shows the following 
(ps aux | grep rails):

```
Gavin      726   0.0  3.8  2590812 158860 s000  S+    9:27am 0:09.90  /Users/Gavin/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.01/bin/ruby script/rails s
```

The RSS is at a cool 158,860 kb 
After a few requests to localhost, this number jumps up to:

```
Gavin      726   0.0 14.1  3031792 592888 s000  S+    9:27am 0:27.00  /Users/Gavin/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.01/bin/ruby script/rails s
```

592,888 kb!!

and with general development use, it goes up again and again and 
again:

```
Gavin      726   1.5 25.0  3487516 1050180 s000  S+    9:27am 0:59.29 /Users/Gavin/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.01/bin/ruby script/rails s
```

I'm running REE using RVM 
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i686-darwin10.6.0], MBARI 
0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.01

The app is using Rails 3.0.6

The application is not particularly SQL intensive and there are almost 
no associations included when records are loaded (not required in the 
architecture).

Am I right in saying this is a memory leak or is there something else 
I should be looking at?

Can anybody offer some advice on how I can solve this?

Thanks!

Here's a full list of the gems used just incase there are any known 
suspects in there:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org' 
gem "omniauth", "0.2.0" 
gem "fb_graph" 
gem 'rails', '>=3.0.6' 
gem 'mysql2' 
gem "delayed_job" 
gem "rvm" 
gem "whenever" 
gem "less" 
gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt" 
gem "twitter" 
gem "paperclip" 
gem "aws-s3" 
gem "RedCloth" 
gem "decent_exposure", :git => "git://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure.git" 
# Application monitoring services 
gem 'hoptoad_notifier', ">=2.4.5" 
gem "newrelic_rpm", ">=2.13.4" 
gem "yahoo-weather", "1.2.0", :require => false 
gem "json", "~>1.4.6" 
gem 'will_paginate', :git => "git://github.com/mislav/will_paginate.git", :branch => "rails3" 
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on' 
gem "aasm", ">=2.2.0", :require => "aasm" 
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.2', :require => 'thinking_sphinx' 
# These gems are not required on the Staging/Production server 
group :development, :test do 
  gem 'capistrano' 
  gem "capistrano-ext" 
  gem "nifty-generators" 
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', :git => "http://github.com/CodeMonkeySteve/factory_girl_rails.git" 
  # Keep on top of the latest RSpec Gems 
  gem "rspec-rails",        :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails.git" 
  gem "rspec",              :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec.git" 
  gem "rspec-core",         :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-core.git" 
  gem "rspec-expectations", :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations.git" 
  gem "rspec-mocks",        :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks.git" 
  gem 'shoulda' 
  gem "mocha" 
  # gives us the mock_model method for mocha 
  gem 'rspec-rails-mocha', '~> 0.3.0' 
  gem "faker" 
  gem "autotest", ">=4.4.6" 
  gem "autotest-growl" 
  gem "autotest-rails" 
  gem "database_cleaner" 
  gem "redgreen" 
  gem "launchy" 
  gem "faker" 
  gem 'ruby-debug' 
  gem "rcov" 
  gem "rdoc" 
  gem "ruby-prof" 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aasm leaks memory very quickly when `cache_classes = false` (which is the default in development mode).  You do use a lot of gems, but I am willing to bet aasm is behind this.

as others have said, it is best to use a memory profiler.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have some memory leaks. Try poking with a memory profiler: https://github.com/ice799/memprof

Comment: Thanks - I've checked out memprof but when I try to load it I get the error:


    Magic for Ruby Mach-O file doesn't match

Comment: Please try to install from github, this is how I installed it. git clone https://github.com/ice799/memprof.git; gem build memprof.gemspec; sudo gem install memprof-*.gem ; tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Roman but still no luck :(

I noticed the problem is a lot less severe when I set cache_classes to "true". Can anybody give me some pointers as to how to find a leak without memprof?

Answer (score 0):

Check config/newrelic.yml for:

```
developer_mode: false|true
```

If it's set to "true" then the memory issue may be this.

Comment: Acht!

OK, so developer_mode was set to true in newrelic.yml

But changing that and restarting still hasn't helped much.

RSS is still climbing with every request.

Comment: it's leaking memory only in development? It's likely that you have some gem (ruby-prof?) which collects data in-memory. Take a look how to identify who's reponsible for the memory leak: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-memory-leaks

Comment: It's leaking memory in both Development mode and Production... but definitely more sever in Dev. mode.

Comment: https://github.com/rubyist/aasm/issues/31 - aasm gem seems that has memory issues, try to disable it and take a look how it performs without it.